# VBA excel control multiple checkboxes with 1 macro

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a quite simple macro to hide the row the checkbox is in when clicked. It works but the problem is there are A LOT of rows.

```
    Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    [3:3].EntireRow.Hidden = CheckBox3.Value
    Range("AB3").Value = True

End Sub
```

I of course can make a separate macro for every single checkbox i have (all 250 of them), but i hope i can avoid a macropage that is 6 pages long.

My question is: is there a way to combine it into 1? the only thing that is different for all of them is the number (in the example its 3).

Comment: Don't know if there is a big difference, but they are ActiveX checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You should create those CheckBoxes programatically and create Class Module to handle events. Here is example how to achieve it:

ClassModule i.e. MyCheckBox:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents m_CheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim m_Row As Long
Public Sub CreateCheckBox(ByVal sh As Worksheet, ByVal rowNumber As Long)
    m_Row = rowNumber
    Set m_CheckBox = sh.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=sh.Cells(rowNumber, 1).Left, Top:=sh.Cells(rowNumber, 1).Top, Width:=108, Height:=19.5).Object
End Sub

Private Sub m_CheckBox_Change()

    MsgBox "I'm in row " & m_Row & " MyValue is " & m_CheckBox.Value

End Sub
```

Module using this code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim chkBoxes As New Collection

Public Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chk As MyCheckBox

    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Set chk = New MyCheckBox
    chk.CreateCheckBox sh, 1
    chkBoxes.Add chk

    Set chk = New MyCheckBox
    chk.CreateCheckBox sh, 2
    chkBoxes.Add chk

End Sub
```

Of course method CreateCheckBox has to be adjusted to your needs (my one is creating checkbox in first column). Global collection in module is required otherwise classes are destroyed automatically when sub is finished and events are never fired. If workbook is opened and closed then this code must be upgraded to either:

1) Recreate classes on Workbook event i.e. open

2) Recreate CheckBoxes every time workbook is opened